# random slowness in a simple SQLite query

Tags: sql, perl, sqlite, dbi

I have code (using Perl's DBI on Linux, if it matters) to update a SQLite database table (~40 million rows) based on a data file that we receive regularly. Part of that code repeatedly performs a very simple select query on the database. Something like the below loop runs within a transaction. **The select query usually takes < 0.01 seconds, but a few percent of the time will take 2 seconds or more**. Any ideas on why? These occasional "slow" selects dominate the runtime and are therefore a big problem for me.

```
while(<UPDATE_FILE>)) {
  my ($val4, $val5) = get_values_from_line($_);
  my $cmd = "SELECT col1, col2, col3... colN FROM TABLE " .
  "WHERE col4 = $val4 AND col5 = $val5 " .
  "ORDER BY col2 desc, col3 desc";

  execute $cmd;
  based on results, insert into or modify the table, or do nothing
}
```

So all that varies for each iteration is the details of the where clause. I don't understand what to look for to figure out what is going on.

**Things I have checked:**

There is a valid index on the columns used in the WHERE clause.

When rerunning the same code twice, it is not always the same queries that are slow; e.g. it is not particular values of $val4 and $val5 that are to blame.

There is no connection between the number of rows returned by the SELECT and the speed of the query. (The number of rows is never large; < 10).

I can see no obvious connection between what was last done in the database and the query speed; in particular, slow queries do not necessarily follow modifications/insertions. (Which I suppose aren't happening anyway yet because the loop is in a transaction?).

$val4 and $val5 can be null but this makes no difference.

Slow queries are typically nonconsecutive. If you run a rerun a particular slow query, it will be fast.

Nothing else is using this database while I try to update it.

**UPDATE:**

EXPLAIN QUERY revealed that SQLite was for some reason choosing to use a different index, one which is inappropriate for this query. When I force the query to run using the correct index by adding "INDEXED BY correct_index", it is always fast. I will try running ANALYZE next to see if that helps the query optimizer.

So that solves my immediate problem, but still leaves me baffled as to what was going on.

**UPDATE #2:**

Some queries are still randomly slow! It's just that with the new index, most queries are < 0.001 secs with the occasional one above 0.1 secs. This is tolerable for this particular application but could spell trouble down the road.

Comment: What is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query?

Comment: Running query plan from the command line:
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE table_name USING COVERING INDEX table_CI (date=?) (~2 rows)
0|0|0|USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY

From within code I get (not sure I'm parsing correctly):
0 0 TABLE table_name WITH INDEX table_CI

In neither case is this the index I expected it to use... I'll see if I can force it to use the "right" index...

Comment: Sorry about ugliness above @CL.  this is my first time commenting and I could't get the hang of the markdown within the five minute window (indeed I wasn't aware there was a five minute window).

Comment: Are you using DBI statement handles to prepare queries? e.g. `$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo, bar FROM table WHERE baz=?");

         $sth->execute( $baz );

         while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
           print "@row\n";
         }`

Comment: To add relevant information to the question, edit the question.

Comment: What does [DBI profiling](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.632/lib/DBI/Profile.pm) tell you?